# How to deal with overly-competitive answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

It does so happen that in a question with high traffic, there is often that one person who down votes every other answers besides theirs in order to pull the other answerers down. I believe this is pretty toxic. I've noticed this on a couple of occasions. While I have no proof, it is quite evident since their answer is the only one that hasn't been down voted.

It could also be the case that a salty answer had their answer down voted due to whatever reason, and feeling resentful about this, down voted all the other answers to that question.

What should be the protocol for handling situations like this? I would consider it unfair not just to me but to everyone who was unfairly down voted.

Comment: I don't see the problem. My own answers are superior to any other answers. They deserve to be down voted. Not admitting that I'm brilliant is the toxic behavior ... Up vote all my things ...

Comment: Where does it happens usually? Is it on super easy and basic questions?

Comment: @rene So it was you all along???? How dare you

Comment: You can't know that an individual didn't just come across 3 answers they thought weren't good enough, downvoted them, and provided their own answer. You can't know that multiple different people didn't independently downvote those other answers. You can't know that it wasn't a completely unrelated person who felt one of x answers was better than the others. The system catches suspicious voting patterns that it cares about, and you can always flag for moderator attention if you think something dodgy is going on. Other than that, ignore and move on

Comment: @AlonEitan The simpler ones generating higher traffic.

Comment: @Clive I agree with you, those cases are definitely true. But as a person you too can pick up suspicious voting patterns, I daresay better than the system can. And I do believe such cases exist as I've fallen victim to them personally.

Comment: It's just speculation though, unless you have access to more data. There is a high enough volume of traffic on SO that it wouldn't be unusual for three separate people to downvote three separate answers, and a fourth not to be downvoted. Assuming bad faith isn't useful, if there's undesirable behaviour happening it needs to be looked at with access to the stats. That's a job for mods, so if you are suspicious, flag

Comment: Right, you have no evidence, no pattern is visible on your own DVed posts.  The only one I see is that you engage in risky behavior.  These are Qs from newbies that have already been answered before and your posts are not researched.  Along with fellow posters' btw, which is okay but don't expect the community to be thrilled about it.  This does otherwise happen, very rarely, the community police always solves the problem.  Typically by recognizing the behavior and with-holding upvotes, the user quickly loses interest in still participating.

Comment: How do you know it was a user that answered that voted, and that they downvoted as a tactical move? We'd love to have access to your remote thought-reading tech! If you don't have such advanced capabilities, please don't make assumptions as to who voted and why.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Take a look here at this comment thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44482250/4909087. This user was trying to bulldoze the OP into downvoting my question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, if you have mod access, please take a look at who down voted my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44482973/4909087

Comment: @Coldspeed: Moderators can't see individual votes, let alone undo them. We have access to *patterns*, not specifics.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, that's all I have to show. My thought-reading tech is proprietary. :)

Comment: @Coldspeed: and *comments* are *not votes*. Even if a user state they voted one way, they could be lying about the votes or the motivation. Even if they told you and told the truth, *then that's their prerogative*. Voting against other answers is **not** fraudulent or disallowed. Moderators will not act on such votes.

Comment: As for that comment, I still think it's inappropriate to tell other users how to vote (and that includes un/accepting answers other than explaining once to a new user how to do so) and I don't think they understand what accepting an answer means, but I still wouldn't call that *bulldozing*. Also, unaccepting an answer isn't the same as down voting it.

Answer (score 1):

As one person downvotes another upvotes so there no way to prove one or two persons are responsible for downvoting other answers even if they want to. Its just that those answers are not good enough so users randomly down votes it.

Comment: What do you mean by no way to prove a downvote of an upvote? When you have [1,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) you also able to see how many upvotes and downvotes were casted on a post. Or maybe you meant something else?

Comment: As @AlonEitan I can see how many separate up/down votes my post received by clicking on the number.

Comment: Yes but you cant control how other random user votes and you cant vote twice on the same post. Even if someone has that intention its just perfectic cause you can improve better in your answers and it will get better attentions.

Comment: I think this answers goes in the right direction but maybe you can elaborate a bit if it is toxic/unfair or not and depending on that, if there needs to be a protocol for example for q/a pairs where all answers except 1 got a single down vote.

Comment: Its not unfair? Its just how we choose to justify not improving.
The term is just competitive.